i have table with same item id with add stock reduce stock but foreach looping duplicate value
Model
$this->db->select('item.item_id, item_stock.*, item_add_stock.*, item_reduce_stock.*');
$this->db->from('item');
$this->db->join('item_stock', 'item_stock.item_stock_id = item.fk_item_stock_id', 'left')   
$this->db->join('item_add_stock', 'item_add_stock.fk_item_id = item.item_id', 'left');  
$this->db->join('item_reduce_stock', 'item_reduce_stock.fk_item_id = item.item_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('fk_user_id', $_SESSION['user_id']);
$this->db->where('item_id', $item_id);

$array = $this->db->get()->result();
return $array;

Controller
function detail(){

    $data = $this->crud_model->user_basic_info();
    $item_id = $this->uri->segment('3');

    $data['item_transactions'] = $this->crud_purchase->item_transactions($item_id);
    $data['item_price'] = $this->crud_purchase->item_price($item_id);
    $data['item_stock'] = $this->crud_purchase->item_stock($item_id);

    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');
    $this->load->view('item/detail');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}

View
<?php foreach ($item_transactions as $transaction):?>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" target="_blank">
        Opening Stock
        </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $transaction->i_s_opening_stock; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo 'Rs.'.$transaction->i_s_total_amount; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" target="_blank">
        Add Stock
        </a>
        <p class="help-block"><?php echo $transaction->i_r_s_date; ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $transaction->i_a_s_qty; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo 'Rs.'.$transaction->i_s_total_amount; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>" target="_blank">
        Reduce Stock
        </a>
        <p class="help-block"><?php echo $transaction->i_r_s_date; ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $transaction->i_r_s_qty; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo 'Rs.'.$transaction->i_s_total_amount; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

Result I am getting
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 8 [item_stock_id] => 10 [i_s_opening_stock] => 1000 [i_s_as_date] => [i_s_unit_price] => 325 [i_s_total_amount] => 325000 [i_s_minimum] => 5 [i_s_location] => [i_a_s_id] => 5 [i_a_s_date] => 02-04-2024 [i_a_s_qty] => 25 [i_a_s_price] => 325 [i_a_s_detail] => test [fk_item_id] => 8 [i_r_s_id] => 4 [i_r_s_date] => 02-04-2024 [i_r_s_qty] => 50 [i_r_s_price] => 325 [i_r_s_detail] => test ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 8 [item_stock_id] => 10 [i_s_opening_stock] => 1000 [i_s_as_date] => [i_s_unit_price] => 325 [i_s_total_amount] => 325000 [i_s_minimum] => 5 [i_s_location] => [i_a_s_id] => 6 [i_a_s_date] => 02-04-2024 [i_a_s_qty] => 75 [i_a_s_price] => 325 [i_a_s_detail] => test [fk_item_id] => 8 [i_r_s_id] => 4 [i_r_s_date] => 02-04-2024 [i_r_s_qty] => 50 [i_r_s_price] => 325 [i_r_s_detail] => test ) 
)


Please tell us what you expect as a result and post a sample of data

i am joining the table but when i loop it with foreach then it display duplicate result which i dont need i need each time single result but not with Group_by hope you understand
